# Identify outliers in scatter plot

Tags: r, bioinformatics, scatter-plot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
gene        AE        CM       PR     CD34     
DDR1  8.020745  7.851901 7.520458 7.948326  
RFC2  7.778460  8.175659 7.978560 8.845708 
PAX8  9.566903  9.589379 9.405003 8.853069  
GUCA1A  5.320824  5.318613 5.333363 5.424622 
UBA7 10.422949 10.193109 9.357451 9.985480 
GAPDH 13.559894 13.739593 13.517791 12.047161 
GAPD 13.619479 13.790955 13.670576 12.994784 
STAT_1 10.175952  9.911392  9.424882 10.024869  
STAT3  7.089633  6.898931  6.654907  5.894336  
STAT4  8.843160  8.746647  8.389753  8.024894
```

I wanted to have a scatterplot for each of the possible pairs and for that I used following R commands

```
d<-read.table("Dataset.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
pairs(~d$AE+d$CM+d$PR+d$CD34,col="red")
```

Now what more, I want is to have the outliers marked with the gene names. for instance, DDR1 has a difference of 0.5 between AE Vs CD34. Hence this should be marked in that plot with gene name (in this case DDR1).

Overall, any gene between the pairs showing a difference of +- 0.5 should be marked.

**Data:** The result of `dput()` of first 100 lines of my data

```
    structure(list(gene = structure(c(25L, 57L, 38L, 47L, 36L), .Label = c("ADAM32", 
"AFG3L1", "AKD1", "ALG10", "ARMCX4", "ATP6V1E2", "BEST4", "C15orf40", 
"C19orf26", "C4orf33", "C8orf45", "C8orf47", "C9orf30", "CATSPER1", 
"CCDC11", "CCDC65", "CCL5", "CILP2", "CNOT7", "CORO6", "CRYZL1", 
"CTCFL", "CYP2A6", "CYP2E1", "DDR1", "EPHB3", "ESRRA", "EYA3", 
"FAM122C", "FAM18B2", "FAM71A", "FLJ30901", "GAPT", "GIMAP1", 
"GSC", "GUCA1A", "HOXD4", "HSPA6", "KLK8", "LEAP2", "MAPK1", 
"MFAP3", "MGC16385", "MSI2", "NCRNA00152", "NEXN", "PAX8", "PDE7A", 
"PIGX", "PRR22", "PRSS33", "PTPN21", "PXK", "RAX2", "RBBP6", 
"RDH10", "RFC2", "SCARB1", "SCIN", "SLC39A13", "SLC39A5", "SLC46A1", 
"SP7", "SPATA17", "SRrp35", "THRA", "TIMD4", "TIRAP", "TMEM106A", 
"TMEM196", "TRIOBP", "TTC39C", "TTLL12", "UBA7", "VPS18", "WFDC2", 
"ZDHHC11", "ZNF333"), class = "factor"), AE = c(8.0207450402, 
7.7784602732, 7.274639204, 9.5669027802, 5.3208241196), CM = c(7.8519007358, 
8.1756591822, 7.8186806878, 9.5893790363, 5.3186130064), PR = c(7.5204580759, 
7.9785595029, 7.3307638794, 9.4050027059, 5.3333625256), CD34 = c(7.9483258833, 
8.8457084131, 6.9874872331, 8.8530693617, 5.4246223945), CMP = c(7.9362235824, 
10.0085488406, 6.6883401632, 9.249816924, 5.4312885508), GMP = c(8.1370096058, 
10.0990080444, 6.7144163183, 9.2157346882, 5.3700062534), Monocytes = c(8.1912723165, 
8.7568163628, 9.2072172453, 9.2086040758, 5.3090689608)), .Names = c("gene", 
"AE", "CM", "PR", "CD34", "CMP", "GMP", "Monocytes"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you `dput` your data please (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: HI, Sorry I am bit lost, How is this gonna help my problem?

Comment: It's going to help _us_ run your code and then help you

Comment: Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `panel` in `pairs()`

Since the condition you have mentioned in the question is not very clear, I chose to assign the gene names based on this condition `d$AE - d$PR >= 0.5` *(you can change it accordingly as per your needs)*. so, if `d$AE - d$PR >= 0.5` I create a new column "labels" containing the corresponding gene name and use the same to put the labels in the chart

```
d$labels = ifelse(d$AE - d$PR >= 0.5, as.character(d$gene), '')
pairs(~d$AE+d$CM+d$PR+d$CD34,col="red", 
       panel=function(x, y, ...){ 
             points(x, y, ...); 
             text(x, y, d$labels, pos = 3, offset = 0.5)
      })
```

[image]

Also check `?text` to change the position of the label as per your needs